# CSS Vertically Center in dynamically sized parent.

Tags: css, reactjs

This is yet another question about centering vertically in a div, but I've tried lots of the solutions discussed in other answers to no avail.

[Here's an example of the code to play with:  https://codesandbox.io/s/z2qzxwk99x](https://codesandbox.io/s/z2qzxwk99x)

The arrow-icon is centering vertically in the viewport, instead of the viewer-wrapper div.  As such, it drops off of the image completely, instead of staying centered vertically, if you make the page very narrow.

```
.viewer-wrapper {
    background-color: #1b8dbb;
    position: relative;
}

.arrow-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 100%;
    line-height: 95vh;
    background-color: #4cae4c;
    margin: auto;
    opacity: .9;
    left: 0px
}

.arrow-icon {
    background-color: orangered;
}

.comic-page {
      object-fit: contain;
      max-height: 95vh;
      width: 100%;
}

<div className="viewer-wrapper"> 
    <div className="arrow-wrap">
      <LeftArrow className="arrow-icon" size={75} />
    </div>

    <img className="comic-page"
        src="http://assets-production.rovio.com/s3fs-public/hatchlings_0.jpg"
      about="This is an image"
    />
  </div>
```

Comment: The problem seems to be rooted in that the arrow-icon's position:absolute is going all the way to the viewport to calculate it's relative position, instead of its nearest positioned ancestor.  I was able to fix this by pulling it outside of the .arrow-wrap div, and have its immediate parent be the .viewer-wrapper.   Any ideas why it isn't finding its relative position properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic here is [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) (and Grids, but Flexbox has way better browser support). Keeping the same HTML layout, you could use somerthig like:

```css
.viewer-wrapper {
    background-color: #1b8dbb;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.arrow-wrap {
    background-color: #4cae4c;
    margin: auto;
    opacity: .9;
}

.arrow-icon {
    background-color: orangered;
}

.comic-page {
      object-fit:contain;
      min-height: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much support you need of IE, there are different ways to accomplish vertical alignment.

If you don't have any need to support IE, you could use the `flex` display property:

```
.viewer-wrapper{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

or, continue with what it looks like you're trying to do. What your missing to do so is the `top:` property. Since you've already correctly made the parent element `position: relative`, setting `top: 50%` will set your arrow to *begin* halfway down the `viewer-wrapper` element. From here you need to set a negative margin to correct for the arrow's height. Since it looks like you specify a size of 75(px?), you can achieve this like:

```
.arrow-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #4cae4c;
    margin-top: -37.5px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

You shouldn't have to set any other margins.

A great resource for this, and what I used to help answer you, is [howtocenterincss.com](http://howtocenterincss.com/).

Comment: I just tried both solutions, and they both have the same problem I've been running into.  They seem to be vertically centering in the viewport, and not the parent div.

Comment: This works once I pulled the .arrow-icon outside of .arrow-wrap and made it a child of .viewer-wrapper.  The problem seems to be rooted in that the arrow-icon's position:absolute is going all the way to the viewport to calculate it's relative position, instead of its nearest positioned ancestor. I was able to fix this by pulling it outside of the .arrow-wrap div, and have its immediate parent be the .viewer-wrapper. Any ideas why it wouldn't be finding its relative position properly?

Comment: It's possible that the react element is not playing well with its div container. What's likely happening is that the `.arrow-wrap` div is actually positioned correctly, but the react element is sort of doing its own thing. Applying the styles directly to element probably did the trick.

Comment: jvial, I thought it might be that, so I swapped out the react arrow-icon for a simple .jpg image, even pulling the entire thing into pure html and CSS, no react or javascript whatsoever.  Same problem.  Something about nesting inside the div, or using the "object-fit: contain" on the .comic-page to define the size of the .viewer-wrapper is breaking the inheritance.